# TestDriven.net shows up in VS 2005, not 2003

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tdd, testdriven.net

Windows XP, TestDriven.NET-3.0.2749  RTM

1. Installed TestDriven.net on my dev machine
2. Does not show in VS2003 ***Enterprise Edition*** add-in manager
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled
4. Shows in VS2005, not 2003 add-in manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a design decision made by Jamie Cansdale. If you want to use Visual Studio 2003 then you need a 2.x version of TestDriven.Net

> At this point I’ve decided to fork TestDriven.Net 2.x and 3.x. Going
>   forward, TestDriven.Net 3 will support Visual Studio 2010, 2008 &
>   2005. TestDriven.Net 2 will continue to support Visual Studio 2008, 2005 & 2003. They will be developed in parallel until the RTM versions
>   of Visual Studio 2010 and TestDriven.Net 3.0 are released. I will then
>   focus my energy on TestDriven.Net 3.x.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2009/10/27/testdriven-net-3-0-alpha-support-for-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx